# Display the number of substrings along with the substring

Tags: python, substring

The input should be manual and must be able to count the number of substrings for any kind of input and also display them

Comment: Hi Sanjana, Welcome to the Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Paste your code in the question, then we can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
# Function to print all sub strings 
def subString(s, n): 
    # Pick starting point in outer loop 
    # and lengths of different strings for 
    # a given starting point
    c=0
    for i in range(n): 
        for len in range(i+1,n+1): 
            print(s[i: len]); #prints substring
            c+=1
    print("Number of substrings:",c)

# Driver program to test above function 
s = "abcd"; 
subString(s,len(s));
```

Comment: I want to print the substrings as well

Comment: It prints the substring as well.Try to run it on your system.

Comment: I want it in this form input:"123123" output:6 substrings -1,12,123,2,23,3